# VMWare, Debian or RPM based

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, rpm

I need some advice, I am installing a monitoring tool on a VMWare server, and I need ask a stupid question :p
Is a VMWare ESXi 5.1 server, Ubuntu or RPM based?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. [VMWare ESXi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESXi#VMware_ESXi) is an independent OS.